# to send hex codes to serial port

Tags: c#

I am using posiflex customer display, and I am trying to clear the display. I have gone through the user's manual, and I found PST command mode, which uses hex codes. I don't know how to pass these hex codes to serial port to clear my display. From the manual, I need to send the following hex numbers:
`14 0E`

I tried the following code to send these bytes, but I don't know how to pass two bytes at the same time.

```
SerialPort sp = new SerialPort();

    sp.PortName = "COM6";
    sp.BaudRate = 9600;
    sp.Parity = Parity.None;
    sp.DataBits = 8;
    sp.StopBits = StopBits.One;
    sp.Open();
   byte[] bytestosend = new byte[1] { 0x0E };

    sp.Write(bytestosend, 0, 1);
    sp.Close();
    sp.Dispose();
    sp = null;
```

When i use this code, no operation is performed (display is not cleared).

Comment: Maybe you should send the `<14>` as well?

Comment: Always include errors and other info. What did / didn't happen here?

Comment: @henk, How do i send 14 along with 0E

Comment: `bytestosend = new byte[] { 0x14, 0x0E };` and `Write(bytestosend, 0, 2);`

Comment: Do **not** close the serial port immediately after writing.  It takes time to get the bytes actually sent, serial ports are slow.  The only sensible thing to do is to open the port when your program starts and not close it until you exit.  If that is immediate anyway then you'll have to delay until BytesToWrite becomes 0.

Comment: thank you so much @hans. i closed the serial port while existing.Now the error does not occur. However I am stil not able to clear my display. :(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To send multiple bytes just use comma to separate the bytes. You should have something like this:

```
sp.PortName = "COM6";
sp.BaudRate = 9600;
sp.Parity = Parity.None;
sp.DataBits = 8;
sp.StopBits = StopBits.One;
sp.Open();
byte[] bytestosend = { 0x14, 0x0E };

sp.Write(bytestosend, 0, bytestosend.Length);
sp.Close();
sp.Dispose();
sp = null;
```

Comment: It would be `sp.Write(bytestosend, 0, 2);` or even better `sp.Write(bytestosend, 0, bytestosend.Length);`

Comment: Thanks @ScottChamberlain - Too much copy and pasting!

Comment: Thanks @belogix. But i got a device attached to this system is not functioning error now

Comment: Well, it should now be sending both bytes. The question is are you sure that is all you need? Often you need STX and ETX with serial commands. Also, what is the "error" you report?

Comment: I am using this pole display fo rthe first time. I tried printing a string "welcome" and it worked. and now i am trying to clear the text, it is not working.

Comment: the pole display is connected properly. but i am getting this new error "device attached to the system is not functioning "